# Problems with Win32 Listview

Tags: c++, listview, winapi

I have 2 problems with ListView in Win32 C++ and hope someone can solve it.

First: I create a ListView and set its style to LVS_REPORT, then I fill in some data. How can I delete an empty row that exists?

[image]

I want something like this (background is gray and there is no additional row):

[image]

Second: When I add data as a row, it enters in the first place and the first row shifts to the last row. How can I change it? I want each new row to enter as the last row.

I tried to change the style of the ListView but get no success.

Comment: The second image looks like a gridview, not a listview. If that is available to C++ from the Win32 SDK, or requires some external library, I don't know.

Comment: yes that is gridview and i didnt find this componet on win32api.i just want my listview row limit to rows that exist ant not more.

Comment: There is no GridView in the Win32 API, that is a custom-made UI control provided by whatever UI framework you are using.

Comment: infact babygrid and simple grid project that exist in codeproject  made custom grid that has this feature

Answer (score 0):

> How can I delete an empty row that exists?

Use [`LVM_DELETEITEM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvm-deleteitem) or [`ListView_DeleteItem()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-listview_deleteitem), specifying the index of the "empty" row.

> I want each new row to enter as the last row.

Use [`LVM_INSERTITEM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvm-insertitem) or [`ListView_InsertItem()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-listview_insertitem), specifying an index that is past the end of the ListView.

Comment: i know how  i can delete or insert item in listview but when listview created these empty row exist even without inserting item,i dont want this happen(similar to second image)

Comment: @Hadi a ListView does not create "empty" rows. And it is clear from your screenshot that your row is not entirely empty, it has data in the 1st column. But in general, if your rows are "empty" then it is because you did not put data in them to begin with (or, you are owner-drawing the ListView and are not drawing the data). That is your fault, not the ListView's. If you don't have data to display, then don't create a row for it. But since you did not show any of your code that is populating the ListView, there is no way for anyone to explain to you why the row is "empty" or how to avoid it.

Comment: My first image show 7 row with data and 4 row without data that are empty.if you create listview and set its style to report and active gridline then you will have empty rows as i mentioned.

Comment: @Hadi What you describe is NOT how a standard ListView works (I've been using ListViews in report view for over 20 years without this problem ever happening to me). You are clearly doing something wrong with how you are using the ListView, but we still can't see exactly what that is. Please edit your question to provide your actual code that is populating the ListView.